# scrollToRowAtIndexPath must be called twice when at Top

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have a tableView that I allow a user to navigate textfields with some arrow keys.  However, when the user is at the top of the table, the arrow button must be pressed twice before first responder will actually change.  The first click displays the next cell, and a second click actually moves focus to the textField in the cell above.  All other directions and arrows work on one click where the focus changes AND scrolling occurs.  with the exception of when the user is at the bottom.  The same thing happens.  (The user cannot do this however because I set scroll to top when a user selects a textfield)

Is there a way to get the same visual effect even when at the top of the table?

My code...

```
switch (arrowButton.tag) {
    case UpArrow:
        destinationIndex =  [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:currentIndex.row - 1 inSection:currentIndex.section];
        newTag = currentTextField.tag;
        break;
    case LeftArrow:
            // Move back one textField.
        if (currentTextField.tag == CustomerDetailsOrderViewControllerCellLeftTextField) {
            // Selected text field is on left.  Select right textfield in the row above
            destinationIndex = [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:currentIndex.row - 1 inSection:currentIndex.section];
            newTag = CustomerDetailsOrderViewControllerCellRightTextField;
        } else {
            // Selected text field is on right.  Select the left textfield in the same row
            destinationIndex = currentIndexPath;
            newTag = CustomerDetailsOrderViewControllerCellLeftTextField;
            }
        break;
    case RightArrow:
        // Move forward one textField.
        if (currentTextField.tag == CustomerDetailsOrderViewControllerCellLeftTextField) {
            // Selected text field is on Left.  Select right textfield
            destinationIndex = currentIndexPath;
            newTag = CustomerDetailsOrderViewControllerCellRightTextField;
        } else {
            // Selected text field is on right.  Select the left textfield in the row below
            destinationIndex = [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:currentIndex.row + 1 inSection:currentIndex.section];
            newTag = CustomerDetailsOrderViewControllerCellLeftTextField;
        }
        break;
    case DownArrow:
        destinationIndex =  [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:currentIndex.row + 1 inSection:currentIndex.section];
        newTag = currentTextField.tag;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
[_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
newTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex] viewWithTag:newTag];
[newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: What happens when you perform the last to lines of code after a slight delay using `dispatch_after`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dispatch_after but I added in a timer and some break points.  Apparently what is going on, is that the scroll animation occurs WAY after everything in that function is executed.

Comment: Jesse, that's why I said to execute the last two lines after a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse, it's the animation that's killing you.

*Try*:

```
    [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
    newTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex] viewWithTag:newTag];
    [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
```

*or*:

```
    [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
    newTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex] viewWithTag:newTag];
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        newTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:destinationIndex] viewWithTag:newTag];
        [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
    });
```

Those are quick and dirty. You can take it a step further and use KVO on the contentOffset of the table and do your firstResponder business when the animation is complete.